# Differentiating Exponential Functional Equation

Tags: calculus, functional-equations

The Functional Equation satisfied by the exponential $f(x)=e^{kx}$ is of the form:

$$
f(x+y)=f(x)f(y), \quad f(0)=1, f'(0)=k
$$

Show that $f'(x) = kf(x)$.

Attempt

I tried applying Chain Rule to the functional equation but it doesnt work.
$$
[f(x+y)]'=f'(x)f(y)+f(x)f'(y)
$$

Let $y=0$, then $f'(x)=f'(x)\cdot 1+k\cdot f(x)$, which is absurd because it is saying 
$$
[e^{kx}]' = [e^{kx}]'+ke^{kx}
$$
So I was wondering why we cannot apply chain rule directly to the Cauchy Functional Equation? It seems that I need to show directly 
$$
[f(x+0)]' = f'(0)f(x)
$$
but I cannot see how to obtain this from the definition of the functional equation.

Comment: Note that you're differentiating with respect to $x$, so you should treat $f(y)$ as a constant (or vice versa).

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1937878/42969.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually only have to apply the definition twice and use the given assumptions in order

\begin{align*}f'(x)&=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} &(\text{definition})\\
&=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x)\cdot f(h)-f(x)}{h}&(\text{functional property})\\
&=f(x)\cdot \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{ f(h)-1}{h}&(\text{linearity})\\
&=f(x)\cdot \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{ f(h)-f(0)}{h}&(\text{given assumption})\\
&=f(x)\cdot f'(0)&(\text{definition})\\
&=f(x)\cdot k&(\text{given assumption})
\end{align*}